# Is Maven able to change the package level of a jar file?

Tags: maven, jar, package

In my application the client has different versions of the same jar file in the classpath. That causes IllegalAccessError exceptions at runtime  while accessing the methods of these jars. I am not able to delete the old version of this jar and at the same time i have to add the new verison of this jar because of the requirements of the project. So I have to modify the package level of new version jar which is provided by maven. For example:

Current situation:
Package level for the Pointer class:

- For old version: com.sun.jna
- For new version: com.sun.jna (actually the main problem is that)

the target situation:
Package level for the Pointer class:

- For old version: com.sun.jna  -->I cannot do any modification on old version
- For new version: com.sun.jna.blabla

So that at run time there will not be any access error.

Briefly, how can i achieve that by using just maven tool?

Regards

Comment: You could probably use https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Comment: If you have the same classes multiple times on the classpath it is just coincidence which one will be loaded which is a no go for an application. You need to clean up your jar's cause there is comething wrong...maven-shade-plugin might be a solution but this will only fix the problem but will not solve the root cause.